# Prevent removing unnecessary white spaces in Kendo Editor

Tags: javascript, html, web, kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I'm using Kendo Editor to insert code snippets to content and it works very well, but when I want to change this formatted code, editor removes unnecessary white spaces, but in my use-case it's wrong.
Have you any idea hot wo fix it?

Print screen with new text in editor
[image]

Print screen with edited text - wrong behaviour.
[image]

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm not found solution, but I found workaround - I'm inserting code into editor by

```
    <pre class="code">...</pre>
```

and kendo stripps unnecessary white spaces, so on server side I'm just replaceing white spaces by non-breaking spaces and new line by breakline... It's not clean solution, but working workaround.